# What is the Pleniglacial age?

Tags: geology

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I was wondering if someone could briefly explain what the Pleniglacial age is and how it fits in with [the geologic time scale](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/help/timeform.php).

Additionally, if someone could recommend a way to keep track of all of these names I would appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Huh? My [first Google result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geochronologic_names) puts *Pleniglacial* in its place... (  73,000 BP  14,500 BP  sub-age  Pleistocene  Northern Europe)

Comment: One tip for names you don't know is to not be afraid of [Latin and Greek prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English#P). If you know what the root plen- means you can have a good grasp on what could be meant, and it is easy to remember.

Answer (score 4):

The Pleniglacial is a stage of the [Weichselian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weichselian_glaciation) [Chronostratigraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronostratigraphy) which is divided in three stubstages (early, middle and late). You can compare the absolute age to the geologic time scale.

[image]

(Data from:
Kasse, C., Huijzer, A. S., Krzyszkowski, D., Bohncke, S. J. P. and Coope, G. R. (1998), Weichselian Late Pleniglacial and Late-glacial depositional environments, Coleoptera and periglacial climatic records from central Poland (Bełchatów). J. Quaternary Sci., 13: 455–469. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1099-1417(1998090)13:5<455::AID-JQS398>3.0.CO;2-T)